# Add new line at the end of Jersey generated JSON

Tags: json, jersey, jackson

I have a Jersey (1.x) based REST service. It uses Jackson 2.4.4 to generate JSON responses. I need to add a newline character at the end of response (cURL users complain that there's no new line in responses). I am using Jersey pretty-print feature (`SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT`).

*current:* `{\n "prop" : "value"\n}`

*wanted:*  `{\n "prop" : "value"\n}\n`

1. I tried using a custom serializer. I need to add `\n` only at the end of the root object. Serializer is defined per data type, which means, if an instance of such class is nested in a response, I will get `\n` in the middle of my JSON.
2. I thought of subclassing `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.java`, overriding `close()`  where i'd add `writeRaw('\n')`, but that feels very hacky.
3. Another idea would be to add Servlet filter which would re-write the response from Jersey Filter, adding the `\n` and incrementing the contentLenght by 1. Seems not only  *hacky*, but also inefficient.
4. I could also give up Jersey taking care of serializing the content and do `ObjectMapper.writeValue() + "\n"`, but this is quite intrusive to my code (need to change many places).

What is the *clean* solution for that problem?

I have found these threads for the same problem, but none of them provides solution:

- http://markmail.org/message/nj4aqheqobmt4o5c
- http://jackson-users.ning.com/forum/topics/add-newline-after-object-serialization-in-jersey

---

**Update**

Finally I went for @arachnid's solution with `NewlineAddingPrettyPrinter` (also bumper Jackson version to 2.6.2). Sadly, it does not work out of the box with Jaskson as [JAX-RS](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/) Json provider. Changed `PrettyPrinter` in `ObjectMapper` does not get propagated to `JsonGenerator` (see [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/blob/master/base/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/base/ProviderBase.java#L593) why). To make it work, I had to add `ResponseFilter` which adds `ObjectWriterModifier` (now I can easily toggle between pretty-print and minimal, based on input param ):

```
@Provider
public class PrettyPrintFilter extends BaseResponseFilter {

    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response) {
        ObjectWriterInjector.set(new PrettyPrintToggler(true));
        return response;
    }

    final class PrettyPrintToggler extends ObjectWriterModifier {

        private static final PrettyPrinter NO_PRETTY_PRINT = new MinimalPrettyPrinter();

        private final boolean usePrettyPrint;

        public PrettyPrintToggler(boolean usePrettyPrint) {
            this.usePrettyPrint = usePrettyPrint;
        }

        @Override
        public ObjectWriter modify(EndpointConfigBase<?> endpoint, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> responseHeaders,
                                   Object valueToWrite, ObjectWriter w, JsonGenerator g) throws IOException {
            if (usePrettyPrint) g.setPrettyPrinter(new NewlineAddingPrettyPrinter());
            else g.setPrettyPrinter(NO_PRETTY_PRINT);
            return w;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, wrapping up (not subclassing) JsonGenerator isn't *too* bad:

```
public static final class NewlineAddingJsonFactory extends JsonFactory {
    @Override
    protected JsonGenerator _createGenerator(Writer out, IOContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return new NewlineAddingJsonGenerator(super._createGenerator(out, ctxt));
    }

    @Override
    protected JsonGenerator _createUTF8Generator(OutputStream out, IOContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return new NewlineAddingJsonGenerator(super._createUTF8Generator(out, ctxt));
    }
}

public static final class NewlineAddingJsonGenerator extends JsonGenerator {
    private final JsonGenerator underlying;
    private int depth = 0;

    public NewlineAddingJsonGenerator(JsonGenerator underlying) {
        this.underlying = underlying;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeStartObject() throws IOException {
        underlying.writeStartObject();
        ++depth;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeEndObject() throws IOException {
        underlying.writeEndObject();
        if (--depth == 0) {
            underlying.writeRaw('\n');
        }
    }

    // ... and delegate all the other methods of JsonGenerator (CGLIB can hide this if you put in some time)
}


@Test
public void append_newline_after_end_of_json() throws Exception {
    ObjectWriter writer = new ObjectMapper(new NewlineAddingJsonFactory()).writer();
    assertThat(writer.writeValueAsString(ImmutableMap.of()), equalTo("{}\n"));
    assertThat(writer.writeValueAsString(ImmutableMap.of("foo", "bar")), equalTo("{\"foo\":\"bar\"}\n"));
}
```

A servlet filter isn't necessarily too bad either, although recently the ServletOutputStream interface has been more involved to intercept properly.

I found doing this via PrettyPrinter problematic on earlier Jackson versions (such as your 2.4.4), in part because of the need to go through an ObjectWriter to configure it properly: only fixed in Jackson 2.6. For completeness, this is a working 2.5 solution:

```
@Test
public void append_newline_after_end_of_json() throws Exception {
    // Jackson 2.6:
//      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
//              .setDefaultPrettyPrinter(new NewlineAddingPrettyPrinter())
//              .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
//      ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer().with(new NewlineAddingPrettyPrinter());
    assertThat(writer.writeValueAsString(ImmutableMap.of()), equalTo("{}\n"));
    assertThat(writer.writeValueAsString(ImmutableMap.of("foo", "bar")),
            equalTo("{\"foo\":\"bar\"}\n"));
}

public static final class NewlineAddingPrettyPrinter
                    extends MinimalPrettyPrinter
                    implements Instantiatable<PrettyPrinter> {
    private int depth = 0;

    @Override
    public void writeStartObject(JsonGenerator jg) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
        super.writeStartObject(jg);
        ++depth;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeEndObject(JsonGenerator jg, int nrOfEntries) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
        super.writeEndObject(jg, nrOfEntries);
        if (--depth == 0) {
            jg.writeRaw('\n');
        }
    }

    @Override
    public PrettyPrinter createInstance() {
        return new NewlineAddingPrettyPrinter();
    }
}
```

Comment: Eventually I went for `PrettyPrinter` solution; white-spaces are not essential part of a generated JSON, and IMO should be managed by a _formatter_ (pretty printer). There's still a problem with Jackson as [JAS-RS](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/) provider - you can overwrite the implementation of prettyPrinter in `ObjectMapper,` but `JsonGenerator` will use the default anyways ((see [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/blob/master/base/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/base/ProviderBase.java#L593)). My solution described in Q update.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet tested but the following should work:

```
public class MyObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

       _defaultPrettyPrinter = com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.MinimalPrettyPrinter("\n");

    // AND/OR

       @Override
       protected PrettyPrinter _defaultPrettyPrinter() {
            return new com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.MinimalPrettyPrinter("\n");
       }

}


public class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {
    ...
    MyObjectMapper mapper = new MyObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT); //enables pretty printing

    // create JsonProvider to provide custom ObjectMapper
    JacksonJaxbJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
    provider.setMapper(mapper);
    register(provider); //register so that jersey use it
}
```

Do not know if this is the "cleanest" solution but it feels less hacky than the others.

Should produce something like

{\n "root" : "1"\n}\n{\n "root2" : "2"\n}

But it seems that does not work if there is only one root element.

Idea is from https://gist.github.com/deverton/7743979

Comment: I have already pretty print configured (not overriding the default `PrettyPrinter` though), and it gives me JSON like: `{\n  "prop" :  "value"\n}`. I think I did not express myself clearly - what I need is a new line *after the whole* JSON entity like: `{\n  "prop" :  "value"\n}\n`. I have tested your solution, but it does not differ functionally from what I currently have.

Comment: I have added examples to the question.

Comment: i did already unterstand this and https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/MinimalPrettyPrinter.java cares about separating root objects. But i would go further in that direction and see if you could tweek the MinimalPrettyPrinter to add a root separator also if there is no second root object.

Comment: Oh, in that case I did not understand. I will give it a try on Monday. Will let you know.

Comment: I have tried using `MinimalPrettyPrinter("\n")`, but as you also thought, it did not work with single object. I find @arachnid's `NewlineAddingPrettyPrinter` hitting the point. Thanks anyways!