# Jackson ObjectMapper - writing value to stream

Tags: java, jackson

I have a requirement to fetch and write thousands of records from DB, convert to json and write to zip file. I am able to write with below implementation as well.

```
    @Override
    public StreamingResponseBody fetchAndWriteOrderAllocationsToFile(LocalDate date) {
        int orderCount = orderDao.getOrderCount(date);
        // Pagination
        return outputStream -> {
            try (ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream))) {
                zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("report.txt"));
                int startIndex = 0, count = orderCount;
                do {
                    List<String> orderSerialNos = orderDao.getOrderSerialNos(date, startIndex, PAGESIZE);
                    orderSerialNos.parallelStream().forEach(orderSerialNo -> {
                        try {
                            writeToStream(zipOut, allocationsService.getAllocationsFromOrderItems(orderSerialNo), objectMapper);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            writeToStream(zipOut, Allocations.builder()
                                .orderSerialNo(orderSerialNo)
                                .build(), objectMapper);
                        }
                    });
                    count -= PAGESIZE;
                    startIndex += PAGESIZE;
                } while (count > 0);
            }
        };
    }

    private static void writeToStream(OutputStream outputStream,
                                      Object result,
                                      ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        try {
            objectMapper.writeValue(outputStream, result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Error writing results to stream", e);
        }
    }
```

However I would like to introduce a new line character(or comma) after every json being written to file.
The closest I got was overriding `PrettyPrinter.writeEndObject` method to something like below and use the overridden `PrettyPrinter` class. This obviously adds new line char to all the sub objects of json as well as every new json. The expectation is to have the new line character only after each json.
Is there any way to accomplish this?

```
        @Override
        public void writeEndObject(JsonGenerator g, int nrOfEntries) throws IOException {
            g.writeRaw("}\n");
        }
```

Above code gives:

```
{"orderSerialNo":"1234-ABCD","orderId":1,"shippingAllocations":[{"recipientId":25,"itemId":3893814,"itemSku":"ABC","quantity":1,"shippingItemId":3893815,"shippingSku":"DEF","shipperId":66,"allocation":0}
],"sdAllocations":[],"idAllocations":[]}
{"orderSerialNo":"6789-EFGH","orderId":2,"shippingAllocations":[{"recipientId":45,"itemId":88,"itemSku":"BLAH","quantity":1,"shippingItemId":78,"shippingSku":"HELP","shipperId":99,"allocation":7.95}
],"sdAllocations":[],"idAllocations":[]}
```

The expectation is:

```
{"orderSerialNo":"1234-ABCD","orderId":1,"shippingAllocations"[{"recipientId":25,"itemId":3893814,"itemSku":"ABC","quantity":1,"shippingItemId":3893815,"shippingSku":"DEF","shipperId":66,"allocation":0}],"sdAllocations":[],"idAllocations":[]}
{"orderSerialNo":"6789-EFGH","orderId":2,"shippingAllocations":[{"recipientId":45,"itemId":88,"itemSku":"BLAH","quantity":1,"shippingItemId":78,"shippingSku":"HELP","shipperId":99,"allocation":7.95}],"sdAllocations":[],"idAllocations":[]}
```

Comment: Why not call `outputStream.write('\n')` inside your `writeToStream` method after calling `objectMapper.writeValue`?

Comment: It doesn't work since its parallelly processed. Also you will see string '\n' in the output file. Also this '\n' gets appended randomly and not after each json, like may be after 5 jsons printed.

Comment: If you're writing to the stream in parallel, how are you guaranteeing the JSON output isn't interleaved?

Comment: From my above code  `orderSerialNos.parallelStream().forEach` is what I meant parallelly processed. The order of JSON's doesn't matter ultimately in the output file.

Comment: Solution described here worked!: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33043697/5220241