# Is there a way to format a JSONObject using Jackson to get the content between braces inline?

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist, jackson

I create a json object from a model composed by 3 array lists.

```
public void jsonWriter() {


    PersonRepository personRepository = new PersonRepository();
    List<Person> personList = personRepository.loadPersonsList();

    FireStationRepository fireStationRepository = new FireStationRepository();
    List<FireStation> fireStationList = fireStationRepository.loadFireStationsList();

    MedicalRecordRepository medicalRecordRepository = new MedicalRecordRepository();
    List<MedicalRecord> medicalRecordList = medicalRecordRepository.loadMedicalRecordsList();

    DataBase dataBase = new DataBase(personList, fireStationList, medicalRecordList);

    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        mapper.writeValue(new File("src/main/resources/data_out.json"), dataBase);
        log.debug("Json file saved");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Json file not saved");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And before creating a json file, I need to format it as the following :

```
"persons": [
    { "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Boyd", "address":"1509 Culver St", "city":"Culver", "zip":"97451", "phone":"841-874-6512", "email":"jaboyd@email.com" },
    { "firstName":"Jacob", "lastName":"Boyd", "address":"1509 Culver St", "city":"Culver", "zip":"97451", "phone":"841-874-6513", "email":"drk@email.com" },
    { "firstName":"Tenley", "lastName":"Boyd", "address":"1509 Culver St", "city":"Culver", "zip":"97451", "phone":"841-874-6512", "email":"tenz@email.com" },
    { "firstName":"Roger", "lastName":"Boyd", "address":"1509 Culver St", "city":"Culver", "zip":"97451", "phone":"841-874-6512", "email":"jaboyd@email.com" },
    { "firstName":"Felicia", "lastName":"Boyd", "address":"1509 Culver St", "city":"Culver", "zip":"97451", "phone":"841-874-6544", "email":"jaboyd@email.com" },
    { "firstName":"Jonanathan", "lastName":"Marrack", "address":"29 15th St", "city":"Culver", "zip":"97451", "phone":"841-874-6513", "email":"drk@email.com" },
    { "firstName":"Tessa", "lastName":"Carman", "address":"834 Binoc Ave", "city":"Culver", "zip":"97451", "phone":"841-874-6512", "email":"tenz@email.com" },
    { "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Duncan", "address":"644 Gershwin Cir", "city":"Culver", "zip":"97451", "phone":"841-874-6512", "email":"jaboyd@email.com" },
    { "firstName":"Foster", "lastName":"Shepard", "address":"748 Townings Dr", "city":"Culver", "zip":"97451", "phone":"841-874-6544", "email":"jaboyd@email.com" },
    { "firstName":"Tony", "lastName":"Cooper", "address":"112 Steppes Pl", "city":"Culver", "zip":"97451", "phone":"841-874-6874", "email":"tcoop@ymail.com" },
    { "firstName":"Lily", "lastName":"Cooper", "address":"489 Manchester St", "city":"Culver", "zip":"97451", "phone":"841-874-9845", "email":"lily@email.com" },
    { "firstName":"Sophia", "lastName":"Zemicks", "address":"892 Downing Ct", "city":"Culver", "zip":"97451", "phone":"841-874-7878", "email":"soph@email.com" },
```

Unfortunately this is what I get :

```
"persons" : [ {
"firstName" : "John",
"lastName" : "Boyd",
"address" : "1509 Culver St",
"city" : "Culver",
"zip" : "97451",
"phone" : "841-874-6512",
"email" : "jaboyd@email.com"
```

The idea should be to format the content between braces to be inline.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove in your code

```
.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
```

because this enables the default pretty printer (Cf. [IDENT_OUTPUT](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#INDENT_OUTPUT)). Without the pretty printer it should be inline again.

Comment: Thanks but without, I get everything in only one line... I though maybe there was another SerializationFeature useful in my case.

Comment: Then use the method `.writeValueAsString(dataBase)` and use the String's method `jsonAsString.replaceAll("\\}\\,", "\\}\\,\n")` in order to incorporate newlines after each json object.

Comment: If this is too dirty for you you can create your own `JsonGenerator` and there overwrite its method `writeEndObject()`: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator.html#writeEndObject-- Then use `JsonGenerator` via `ObjectMapper.writeValue(JsonGenerator g, Object value)`. StackOverflow has your issue already handled: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33040791/add-new-line-at-the-end-of-jersey-generated-json